How to use VBA to open a document and remove its attached template when that template has an autonew() macro
A VBA macro can be used to open a document and modify or manipulate it, but if the document was created by a template that has an autonew() macro, the macro stops running (without any error message) immediately after opening the document.
I tested this by having the macro execute the following steps:

open document attached to Normal.dotx,

attach a different template that has an autonew() macro

save and close document

re-open the document

display a message box with the file name.


Documents.Open strPath & "test.docx"
With ActiveDocument
    .AttachedTemplate = strPathToTemplate & strTemplateName 'template with an autonew() macro
    .Save
    .Close
End with
Documents.Open strPath & "test.docx"
Msgbox ActiveDocument.Name

Running the macro the first time, it stops after step 4, with test.doc remaining open as the active document.  The message is not displayed, and neither is any error message.
Running the macro again (but with the document open), it displays the message (i.e., it executes step 5).
When I change the 3rd line ".AttachedTemplate = ..." to point to a macro-enabled template without an autonew() or autoopen() macro, the macro does not stop at step 4 and the message displays.

This approach works for me:
Sub Test()
Dim wdDoc As Document
Const StrDocNm As String = "Document Path\Test.docx"
Const StrTmplt As String = "Template Path\Template.dotm"
Application.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros True
Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=StrDocNm)
wdDoc.AttachedTemplate = StrTmplt
wdDoc.Close True
Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=StrDocNm)
Application.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros False
MsgBox wdDoc.Name
End Sub


Your suggested approach works for me too, as long as the attached template for Test.docx (before you run the macro) does not have an autonew() or autoopen() macro.  If the document's attached template has an autonew() macro or autoopen() macro, the Test() macro stops running after opening the document.

Code revised to disable auto macros.
